# A most dangerous game

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My mind is hazy, I'm completely stunned
Is it seriously dangerous - should I run?
What day is it? What month? What year?
Is it night so soon filled with shadows I fear?
Take heed! Beware! My brother, my friend
I paid the price so you can see the journey's end

Cause it's all the same - all but one affair
Should I tell you the truth or do I lie?

**The answer is a word**

Hint:

> Each line has one
>  Each one has four
>  Look at the sum
>  And find one more

Comment: umm...is it paranoia 0_o

Comment: If Meta45's answer, or anything like it, is correct then this surely wants the "knowledge" tag. Maybe also another more specific one, but perhaps that would give too much away.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I dont believe the knowledge tag is necessary here

Comment: All I can keep thinking is this is what my brain felt like when I got a concussion.

Comment: I think the six words for the first six lines are weed, bold, time, star, heed, stop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> Dare

In light of the hint, we are trying to find a four letter word for each line.

My mind is hazy, I'm completely stunned

> Daze

Is it seriously dangerous - should I run?

> Dire

What day is it? What month? What year?

> Date

Is it night so soon filled with shadows I fear?

> Dark

Take heed! Beware! My brother, my friend

> Care

I paid the price so you can see the journey's end

> Fare

Cause it's all the same - all but one affair

> Every line's answer is one letter different from DARE.

Should I tell you the truth or do I lie?

> Cheeky false-rhyme leaving the reader expecting 'dare' as the final word.

A most dangerous game

> Truth or Dare can be a dangerous game.

Comment: On point! Only thing different is in the "Take heed!" line, I intended "care". And I'm super happy that the "cheeky false-rhyme" was discovered haha :D. I can't edit it myself, so I'll accept this answer upon your edit :)

Comment: @indubitablee Done

Answer (score -1):

I think it is:

> subject 16 of the game assassin's creed II (haven't finished the game yet, so not sure if all lines are correct)

My mind is hazy, I'm completely stunned

> being to long in the animus has bad effects on your mind and health

Is it seriously dangerous - should I run?

> trying to escape from absergo

What day is it? What month? What year?

> he's so long in the animus that his memories become twisted in past, present and future

Is it night so soon filled with shadows I fear?

> in the end he was completely mad

Take heed! Beware! My brother, my friend

> he warns the player, his "assassin brother"

I paid the price so you can see the journey's end

> subject 16 died in the animus, but he left clues so you might get to the end

Cause its all the same - all but one affair

> getting Eden's Apple and the power with it

Should I tell you the truth or do I lie?

> subject 16 left a trail of clues to find the truth.

A most dangerous game

> trying to find and get the Eden's Apple

Comment: nice try but not the answer. outside knowledge isnt needed for this riddle. the lines (i hope) fit more snugly with the answer